# Calcular monto total de trabajos por región: contando cuántas veces se encuentran, multiplicando por su monto correspondiente y sumar los resultados

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo 5 tablas, una con todos los trabajos realizados en una comuna, una tabla con los códigos de las comunas y sus nombres, y así también para las provincias y las regiones a las que pertenecen. También hay una tabla que especifica los tipos de trabajos con su nombre y monto individual.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `comunas` (
  `COD_PROV` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `COD_COMUNA` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMBRE_COMUNA` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `comunas` VALUES (10,20,'ARICA'),(10,21,'CAMARONES'),(11,22,'PUTRE'),(11,23,'GENERAL LAGOS'),(12,24,'LINARES'),(12,25,'COLBÚN'),(12,26,'LONGAVÍ'),(12,27,'PARRAL'),(13,28,'CAUQUENES'),(13,29,'CHANCO'),(13,30,'PELLUHUE'),(14,31,'LEBU'),(14,32,'ARAUCO'),(14,33,'CAÑETE'),(14,34,'CONTULMO'),(14,35,'CURANILAHUE'),(14,36,'LOS ALAMOS'),(14,37,'TIRÚA'),(15,38,'LOS ANGELES'),(15,39,'ANTUCO'),(15,40,'CABRERO'),(15,41,'LAJA'),(15,42,'MULCHÉN'),(15,43,'NACIMIENTO'),(15,44,'NEGRETE'),(15,45,'QUILACO'),(15,46,'QUILLECO'),(15,47,'SAN ROSENDO'),(15,48,'SANTA BÁRBARA'),(15,49,'TUCAPEL'),(15,50,'YUMBEL'),(15,51,'ALTO BIOBÍO'),(16,52,'CONCEPCIÓN'),(16,53,'CORONEL'),(16,54,'CHIGUAYANTE'),(16,55,'FLORIDA'),(16,56,'HUALQUI'),(16,57,'LOTA'),(16,58,'PENCO'),(16,59,'SAN PEDRO DE LA PAZ'),(16,60,'SANTA JUANA'),(16,61,'TALCAHUANO'),(16,62,'TOMÉ'),(16,63,'HUALPÉN'),(17,64,'TEMUCO'),(17,65,'CUNCO'),(17,66,'CURARREHUE'),(17,67,'FREIRE'),(17,68,'LAUTARO'),(17,69,'LONCOCHE'),(17,70,'MELIPEUCO'),(18,71,'ANGOL'),(18,72,'COLLIPULLI'),(18,73,'CURACAUTÍN'),(18,74,'ERCILLA'),(18,75,'LONQUIMAY'),(18,76,'VICTORIA');



CREATE TABLE `historico` (
  `COD_COMUNA` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `MES` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO_ARREGLO` smallint DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `historico` VALUES (22,4,53),(47,3,51),(57,4,52),(60,12,55),(68,11,53),(47,11,55),(64,5,53),(24,10,52),(33,10,51),(26,4,53),(29,3,51),(41,8,54),(62,5,55),(48,1,53),(52,12,51),(55,8,53),(43,4,55),(26,1,55),(58,10,53),(64,3,53),(71,1,54),(76,7,51),(57,1,52),(26,1,51),(35,8,52),(35,6,52),(67,12,51),(25,5,51),(27,1,55),(70,1,51),(38,11,52),(52,1,55),(73,8,55),(69,1,55),(58,9,52),(38,9,54),(74,6,51),(46,2,53),(21,1,51),(64,8,53),(43,1,53),(68,9,52),(34,5,55),(25,1,53),(60,12,54),(63,2,53),(58,5,52),(58,2,52),(32,10,52),(28,1,52),(75,11,53),(39,7,51),(74,11,52),(55,11,54),(52,3,52),(22,7,52),(67,6,55),(44,7,55),(69,10,52),(29,11,51),(33,4,53),(30,6,52),(63,7,54),(27,6,54),(42,4,51),(38,3,55),(68,12,54),(46,3,54),(33,10,51),(55,8,55),(57,8,54),(37,2,53),(63,7,52),(52,2,54),(29,11,54),(60,6,52),(48,3,51),(24,8,51),(43,11,55),(56,1,52),(22,11,51),(68,3,51),(56,4,51),(54,4,52),(33,4,51),(40,3,53),(30,12,51),(25,8,54),(41,6,51),(27,12,54),(34,4,51),(61,6,52),(75,7,53),(26,10,52),(75,8,54),(68,10,54),(54,1,54),(33,4,51),(21,8,51),(25,1,52),(62,9,52),(72,4,52),(39,7,52),(38,6,54),(49,3,52),(39,12,51),(53,5,51),(31,6,51),(29,9,51),(55,11,52),(44,7,55),(61,2,55),(52,10,51),(54,1,55),(29,6,51),(65,1,54),(55,6,54),(29,2,51),(58,2,54),(70,3,52),(38,7,53),(66,6,52),(44,12,53),(61,7,51),(30,6,52),(65,2,52),(25,7,52),(76,12,52),(58,5,55),(56,6,51),(74,10,55),(44,10,52),(46,6,55),(41,12,55),(28,2,53),(57,9,51),(61,9,55),(38,9,53),(27,1,54),(38,3,54),(40,4,55),(69,2,52),(59,4,52),(43,6,53),(28,6,54),(74,7,51),(30,7,53),(67,1,53),(51,5,53),(72,2,54),(55,12,52),(68,6,55),(46,9,53),(67,10,51),(71,1,55),(58,9,51),(29,6,55),(25,2,54),(54,2,55),(31,7,54),(35,2,51),(28,2,54),(23,1,54),(42,6,52),(40,10,53),(44,11,53),(67,4,52),(71,12,51),(57,4,53),(25,7,51),(72,3,53),(66,8,51),(27,3,53),(71,8,54),(51,9,52),(38,1,54),(27,5,53),(23,11,51),(76,10,55),(30,12,53),(74,7,52),(25,3,52),(64,9,54),(27,7,54),(20,4,52),(55,1,53),(31,11,52),(69,3,54),(57,2,55),(71,3,52),(59,9,52),(24,10,55),(72,10,51),(59,7,53),(55,4,54),(35,1,52),(75,10,51),(35,7,53),(72,1,52),(63,4,53),(35,5,52),(73,6,55),(74,6,53),(50,4,51),(76,7,53),(63,11,53),(59,4,54),(68,3,51),(38,5,54),(53,8,51),(67,9,55),(76,4,52),(67,3,54),(30,6,51),(56,6,51),(55,7,54),(28,11,53),(64,5,53),(44,12,53),(50,6,55),(73,7,51),(40,9,54),(46,2,53),(31,12,54),(55,9,54),(65,1,55),(36,3,53),(25,1,54),(74,1,51),(22,3,52),(45,11,53),(31,1,52),(30,9,52),(59,9,55),(47,7,55),(37,1,55),(69,4,52),(73,10,51),(58,2,55),(45,9,54),(76,8,51),(70,4,55),(72,9,55),(45,3,52),(38,8,55),(46,5,53),(55,2,55),(42,3,54),(50,4,52),(67,4,55),(41,6,52),(51,4,51),(38,7,54),(36,12,52),(53,10,52),(24,4,51),(31,6,53),(63,12,53),(23,7,54),(63,9,52),(38,6,52),(64,12,55),(39,12,52),(47,3,54),(22,4,53),(55,4,53),(34,8,54),(25,8,54),(59,3,55),(54,7,54),(69,4,51),(45,1,52),(62,10,55),(24,5,55),(50,9,53),(48,2,52),(46,12,51),(73,10,52),(30,2,52),(45,4,54),(28,12,54),(25,3,55),(26,3,53),(75,10,53),(76,10,54),(60,11,52),(47,4,55),(25,10,52),(34,12,55),(29,9,53),(36,1,54),(34,7,51),(47,2,52),(42,7,51),(40,3,52),(20,4,54),(45,10,53),(29,8,55),(35,2,54),(65,12,52),(53,4,52),(71,11,51),(32,2,52),(66,10,53),(64,7,54),(46,3,53),(32,1,53),(45,6,54),(54,12,55),(66,2,52),(69,10,53),(42,3,53),(45,4,51),(46,7,55),(39,4,53),(46,12,53),(23,1,54),(68,6,53),(35,2,53),(42,11,55),(52,8,55),(61,7,55),(62,11,51),(74,7,55),(22,5,53),(22,10,52),(74,10,54),(69,1,55),(76,2,51),(29,10,55),(58,9,52),(25,9,53),(45,12,55),(50,4,51),(53,10,51),(24,5,52),(32,10,55),(71,12,54),(62,4,54),(75,5,55),(20,11,54),(45,5,51),(37,11,52),(46,1,55),(54,9,51),(24,5,55),(48,5,55),(31,2,51),(56,8,51),(53,3,52),(34,9,53),(68,10,51),(34,1,55),(44,6,52),(24,3,54),(59,10,51),(65,9,54),(60,8,51),(27,11,55),(68,11,53),(42,3,53),(42,8,51),(68,8,53),(28,9,51),(58,6,51),(47,8,55),(36,8,53),(27,7,55),(21,5,54),(35,12,53),(71,10,55),(22,8,54),(64,9,51),(64,12,52),(30,7,55),(27,12,55),(40,8,53),(68,11,55),(56,1,51),(75,6,53),(56,2,51),(25,7,54),(25,3,52),(25,9,51),(61,8,51),(35,11,53),(35,12,54),(67,4,54),(56,11,55),(37,3,51),(54,9,55),(49,6,52),(56,8,53),(74,7,54),(21,7,55),(23,6,51),(62,12,55),(73,12,54),(26,4,53),(57,11,55),(25,2,54),(25,2,55),(56,2,54),(62,1,55),(20,10,55),(60,6,54),(50,2,52),(53,7,55),(61,3,52),(39,9,54),(38,6,51),(65,4,55),(52,8,54),(67,1,52),(57,8,52),(56,6,55),(46,6,55),(26,6,53),(71,7,51),(35,4,52),(20,10,52),(25,2,55),(45,9,51),(25,6,52),(38,8,54),(58,4,53),(71,11,53),(28,9,52),(73,1,53),(30,10,51),(20,3,52),(63,11,51),(28,12,53),(54,4,54),(70,2,54),(48,4,53),(21,2,54),(70,2,53),(71,11,54),(33,7,51),(64,11,55),(38,5,55),(47,12,53),(76,1,53),(73,3,54),(58,9,55),(52,1,53),(42,6,51),(20,5,52),(25,6,54),(45,3,55),(54,4,53),(74,11,54),(40,4,52),(41,7,54),(48,1,54),(29,1,51),(24,1,51),(30,5,52),(25,11,55),(74,8,52),(21,10,51),(57,7,51),(28,5,51),(61,8,51),(49,11,53),(76,4,55),(72,8,52),(74,10,55),(30,6,52),(41,2,54),(38,4,52),(46,9,54),(21,9,52),(24,10,54),(29,4,51),(60,1,53),(36,12,53),(71,7,53),(39,1,53),(45,4,51),(50,8,52),(51,9,53),(21,9,53),(67,9,53),(67,2,51),(32,1,54),(43,6,54),(52,2,51),(64,3,54),(23,8,51),(62,5,55),(61,7,51),(20,8,53),(61,12,51),(45,11,55),(47,6,52),(67,9,55),(72,8,55),(75,11,52),(38,6,52),(45,10,52),(42,9,51),(43,7,51),(23,12,51),(60,12,51),(53,5,52),(56,2,54),(53,12,55),(50,11,52),(63,12,55),(31,1,53),(47,11,54),(51,10,55),(25,11,53),(39,1,52),(20,12,55),(76,5,51),(64,10,53),(65,9,54),(20,12,54),(67,7,52),(42,8,52),(31,7,54),(75,10,53),(38,3,55),(52,8,51),(58,7,54),(22,12,52),(48,5,52),(21,2,51),(35,7,53),(28,12,54),(49,1,51),(39,9,53),(44,12,53),(44,4,55),(44,7,55),(38,9,55),(70,8,52),(21,12,53),(40,7,55),(66,12,53),(50,8,54),(52,1,53),(65,11,53),(49,1,55),(68,6,53),(63,10,52),(72,6,51),(38,4,52),(30,4,55),(70,3,51),(36,1,52),(23,12,54),(36,3,52),(56,7,55),(57,10,51),(22,11,55),(44,1,55),(33,6,51),(38,8,53),(60,6,51),(48,1,55),(29,7,53),(20,3,55),(36,7,55),(65,12,52),(47,7,54),(70,1,51),(43,2,53),(68,9,54),(73,12,54),(71,11,51),(54,4,51),(37,3,51),(61,1,51),(59,4,55),(75,3,51),(39,7,55),(36,12,55),(39,1,54),(60,12,53),(25,3,52),(66,1,51),(54,4,54),(20,11,51),(35,11,52),(38,2,55),(68,12,51),(52,8,53),(57,5,52),(72,9,52),(23,4,53),(68,12,52),(61,1,54),(37,4,55),(38,1,53),(21,9,55),(40,5,54),(49,3,52),(34,5,54),(50,6,55),(67,8,53),(29,2,55),(49,11,52),(60,5,54),(22,1,51),(47,8,53),(28,1,51),(35,2,55),(20,6,52),(50,9,52),(36,11,54),(36,10,53),(68,5,53),(58,9,55),(41,7,53),(45,10,51),(60,5,54),(59,5,52),(59,3,51),(72,9,51),(33,8,54),(59,6,54),(28,1,54),(54,6,55),(50,10,53),(24,6,52),(59,1,55),(55,10,51),(31,6,53),(71,10,52),(50,2,52),(51,2,53),(67,3,51),(33,12,53),(39,8,54),(32,12,52),(35,7,55),(52,9,55),(68,7,51),(41,1,51),(21,1,52),(50,1,52),(74,1,52),(43,8,54),(34,12,52),(66,9,55),(65,12,52),(62,1,51),(28,1,51),(66,9,55),(34,8,52),(56,2,53),(43,5,54),(30,6,54),(66,10,51),(24,1,54),(31,6,55),(21,6,52),(48,11,53),(47,4,51),(65,8,52),(23,5,51),(27,8,55),(45,7,52),(28,7,52),(47,1,55),(75,7,52),(37,9,53),(31,6,53),(28,7,53),(71,4,53),(57,1,53),(72,8,54),(70,12,54),(60,5,53),(62,10,53),(36,9,54),(23,4,55),(37,6,54),(59,4,52),(41,8,54),(71,5,55),(30,5,55),(60,7,55),(35,5,52),(46,12,53),(58,3,53),(49,7,53),(68,4,52),(44,10,52),(46,11,53),(36,2,51),(44,6,51),(56,5,55),(52,4,51),(38,8,55),(27,4,53),(40,7,53),(45,10,54),(75,3,55),(26,12,53),(75,2,53),(27,1,55),(70,2,55),(71,9,55),(60,5,52),(62,9,55),(32,10,51),(69,9,51),(39,11,54),(29,11,51),(52,12,53),(64,11,54),(43,10,51),(47,2,52),(60,5,53),(35,10,51),(32,4,51),(34,3,52),(32,6,53),(48,10,52),(41,7,55),(54,10,51),(30,11,51),(71,2,53),(29,11,51),(62,5,55),(76,10,51),(73,2,54),(37,4,52),(65,1,52),(54,1,51),(29,9,51),(69,2,51),(55,1,54),(56,8,55),(51,6,54),(20,4,52),(45,3,52),(55,4,51),(50,10,55),(60,12,52),(65,10,51),(38,2,51),(44,8,53),(37,5,55),(29,1,51),(62,5,55),(39,7,55),(75,8,51),(58,8,52),(36,2,53),(55,11,51),(61,5,53),(67,10,51),(50,7,55),(50,8,54),(38,7,55),(75,3,55),(44,9,55),(22,1,54),(54,1,53),(73,12,54),(31,9,53),(29,11,53),(65,1,53),(32,4,54),(40,9,51),(44,12,54),(49,2,55),(32,12,52),(73,5,52),(24,4,52),(24,6,54),(50,6,55),(22,1,53),(57,10,53),(65,7,54),(60,2,54),(41,3,53),(74,1,55),(60,7,54),(60,2,55),(41,7,54),(29,11,53),(53,3,54),(37,10,52),(59,4,54),(73,6,54),(43,4,53),(37,12,52),(43,1,55),(20,4,53),(75,6,55),(56,6,52),(40,2,52),(41,8,53),(33,2,54),(46,5,52),(43,11,53),(26,9,55),(67,8,53),(23,7,51),(23,11,53),(56,6,53),(35,8,54),(25,3,52),(22,2,55),(50,7,55),(30,9,54),(71,7,54),(70,3,54),(28,7,53),(42,11,51),(55,3,53),(48,8,54),(72,1,52),(62,7,54),(35,12,51),(63,4,55),(38,4,52),(36,12,54),(57,1,51),(48,8,54),(52,9,54),(73,1,53),(23,9,54),(41,12,55),(42,10,53),(50,1,54),(71,9,51),(54,3,53),(46,6,54),(42,10,55),(71,7,52),(27,4,52),(49,10,54),(61,5,55),(60,12,51),(63,10,53),(30,5,53),(36,8,51),(68,6,54),(21,9,53),(45,10,54),(69,9,53),(50,3,53),(73,1,52),(61,6,54),(39,7,54),(61,6,54),(44,3,55),(24,4,52),(69,4,52),(39,7,53),(49,3,52),(38,3,53),(63,7,52),(72,6,55),(52,3,53),(25,12,53),(59,12,52),(50,2,51),(71,4,51),(32,12,51),(24,8,51),(40,2,53),(56,6,55),(52,3,55),(42,9,52),(48,8,52),(70,5,53),(24,2,55),(36,6,51),(58,2,53),(38,7,52),(50,6,51),(37,11,54),(73,1,55),(55,5,55),(76,7,55),(54,10,51),(65,11,51),(42,1,53),(30,11,54),(55,9,55),(60,3,54),(72,1,53),(28,9,51),(34,2,55),(31,8,54),(73,9,54),(22,3,51),(76,8,55),(29,5,55),(24,3,52),(55,6,54),(38,8,53),(49,7,51),(76,10,54),(62,4,52),(53,1,55),(43,5,52),(46,2,55),(70,11,51),(22,10,54),(30,11,54),(72,11,53),(45,3,51),(60,7,51),(44,7,52),(27,5,51),(27,4,53),(50,5,55),(73,1,54),(76,3,55),(74,2,51),(43,3,55),(64,5,53),(53,12,54),(54,5,55),(73,8,55),(55,5,55),(33,12,54),(56,2,54),(65,2,55),(54,3,52),(70,5,52),(70,6,53),(46,2,55),(26,9,51),(36,11,51),(73,6,54),(53,8,53),(27,12,51),(54,5,53),(31,12,53),(24,12,55),(34,2,51),(45,7,51),(47,2,52),(44,1,52),(76,7,53),(67,2,52),(59,9,53),(36,9,55),(41,10,51),(38,10,53),(52,8,52),(37,2,53),(73,7,55),(34,9,53),(30,6,55),(26,12,55),(41,7,53),(54,9,52),(73,12,52),(43,9,53),(40,2,52),(53,11,55),(22,5,55),(35,10,52),(54,12,55),(72,5,55),(68,2,55),(48,12,52),(69,7,54),(68,9,52),(66,2,54),(43,9,51),(39,5,52),(20,12,52),(62,10,52),(31,10,54),(23,11,53),(50,10,54),(41,7,54),(75,9,54),(23,2,51),(54,5,51),(49,9,54),(60,5,55),(65,4,55),(53,8,54),(44,3,55),(21,11,55),(40,1,54),(74,1,55),(60,4,55),(70,4,55),(54,2,53),(39,3,53),(49,3,51),(71,5,54),(27,11,51),(58,2,52),(34,7,53),(30,9,55),(58,4,53),(52,11,54),(41,6,51),(63,12,54),(32,3,55),(41,11,55),(41,2,54),(48,11,53),(36,12,53),(33,7,52),(74,2,53),(34,7,54),(54,1,54),(41,6,54),(74,4,51),(31,7,52),(38,4,52),(52,8,55),(45,8,52),(59,10,53),(73,9,53),(51,12,52),(42,11,53),(39,4,51),(61,9,55),(74,7,52),(25,10,51),(25,2,51),(58,1,51),(45,4,53),(62,4,52),(28,1,52),(29,3,55),(69,11,51),(76,12,53),(50,2,54),(61,3,54),(35,7,55),(25,9,55),(69,1,54),(62,5,55),(24,1,54),(52,4,53),(68,11,54),(44,12,53),(51,6,53),(31,11,51),(53,11,52),(42,7,53),(40,11,54),(69,6,53),(72,2,55),(66,5,55),(30,4,52),(35,3,51),(24,10,54),(47,3,54),(66,3,54),(33,11,54),(40,12,54),(23,4,54),(33,12,51),(20,7,51),(46,5,52),(60,2,52),(73,5,53),(64,5,51),(49,6,53),(68,9,51),(52,4,54),(36,8,52),(66,5,53),(24,12,53),(33,8,51),(62,3,52),(50,1,55),(24,6,55),(64,8,51),(24,8,52),(53,3,53),(71,3,55),(32,4,55),(32,1,55),(36,4,55),(46,3,51),(23,1,53),(29,10,53),(56,9,53),(48,6,52),(30,4,51),(37,7,51),(31,11,51),(46,11,54),(39,12,53),(51,8,54),(51,10,54),(57,1,52),(34,5,52),(33,3,53),(72,6,55),(71,8,55),(37,5,52),(76,4,52),(24,9,52),(40,6,53),(60,4,54),(62,4,51),(38,10,52),(52,2,52),(69,2,52),(41,10,54),(54,2,54),(59,1,51),(71,4,53),(38,9,51),(30,7,54),(58,7,53),(74,12,54),(56,9,53),(46,7,54),(57,9,51),(48,8,55),(51,11,55),(33,1,53),(51,7,51),(45,6,52),(38,6,54),(32,8,54),(22,7,52),(26,5,55),(30,12,51),(69,10,51),(66,8,53),(70,3,52),(68,12,51),(37,11,51),(40,11,52),(71,9,53),(40,6,53),(44,7,52),(51,5,54),(29,3,52),(59,3,53),(23,8,55),(69,6,55),(68,8,55),(39,9,55),(72,5,52),(47,1,54),(36,2,52),(56,6,51),(60,12,55),(59,7,52),(73,7,52),(64,12,53),(24,4,52),(70,11,55),(20,3,55),(31,9,53),(56,2,54),(40,2,53),(27,1,51),(32,3,54),(66,3,52),(47,7,54),(74,10,51),(43,8,51),(20,9,51),(46,3,51),(47,9,51),(37,11,54),(29,6,51),(57,4,52),(23,2,55),(71,5,52),(51,3,52),(30,8,54),(31,2,51),(60,6,53),(44,2,52),(42,1,53),(62,5,51),(52,5,54),(48,9,54),(44,6,54),(59,12,54),(75,4,54),(51,3,55),(20,7,54),(60,11,54),(35,1,54),(51,9,51),(38,11,52),(61,12,51),(56,9,55),(60,1,52),(58,12,52),(63,5,51),(56,3,51),(65,11,55),(63,6,55),(48,3,51),(28,2,52),(32,1,52),(42,10,52),(52,1,51),(26,11,55),(69,1,54),(42,12,51),(39,6,55),(47,7,55),(59,9,51),(54,1,54),(45,5,54),(46,4,54),(33,10,51),(28,11,52),(20,6,53),(49,8,53),(56,7,51),(70,5,51),(23,2,52),(67,6,53),(74,6,51),(38,2,52),(59,4,54),(64,3,52),(52,10,51),(76,8,52),(61,12,54),(72,1,52),(65,1,54),(28,10,53),(74,6,53),(23,6,54),(37,8,51),(20,8,54),(56,12,54),(48,11,54),(49,5,54),(73,8,55),(57,4,53),(71,7,52),(36,12,52),(34,11,51),(72,5,52),(48,9,51),(20,11,55),(43,1,53),(50,12,51),(28,5,51),(40,7,53),(66,11,51),(23,1,54),(27,11,51),(42,9,55),(47,4,54),(55,3,54),(27,11,53),(63,3,53),(50,11,54),(45,5,52),(63,2,55),(46,3,54),(24,12,51),(60,10,54),(55,11,53),(72,10,53),(56,2,52),(61,1,55),(54,6,53),(42,2,52),(30,11,54),(38,11,53),(20,2,53),(33,11,52),(46,7,54),(38,11,53),(29,10,54),(20,5,53),(55,10,54),(36,8,51),(57,9,55),(69,1,55),(44,3,53),(74,2,55),(33,12,54),(45,9,51),(23,8,55),(75,11,52),(46,11,53),(71,2,51),(47,11,52),(75,7,51),(71,11,54),(54,9,52),(43,8,52),(62,11,51),(42,5,53),(61,11,55),(64,11,51),(64,8,55),(38,9,51),(20,10,53),(45,6,53),(61,3,55),(63,8,54),(51,12,55),(72,2,54),(35,7,51),(43,12,53),(67,10,55),(33,7,55),(38,7,55),(60,11,54),(70,3,54),(75,4,52),(47,11,53),(42,11,54),(23,5,51),(41,10,55),(37,4,51),(33,7,54),(48,2,51),(55,4,54),(46,4,54),(73,1,52),(22,6,52),(59,10,54),(27,7,54),(24,8,54),(64,7,55),(41,2,55),(43,11,53),(24,9,55),(34,7,53),(67,5,53),(36,7,55),(75,12,51),(56,10,55),(37,2,51),(58,4,53),(43,9,52),(68,4,52),(62,9,53),(48,2,51),(28,9,52),(46,5,53),(63,11,55),(69,6,52),(32,5,55),(48,9,51),(53,5,52),(47,5,54),(41,4,52),(52,8,51),(76,7,52),(33,5,54),(30,5,52),(71,3,52),(52,8,52),(33,8,53),(67,4,54),(61,12,52),(73,2,53),(55,11,55),(60,5,54),(33,10,54),(32,12,55),(41,12,53),(48,5,53),(26,3,55),(39,8,54),(67,1,54),(60,9,54),(66,12,54),(22,5,51),(37,12,54),(25,5,55),(23,7,54),(45,1,55),(41,2,51),(68,6,51),(49,10,51),(66,4,51),(74,10,51),(24,12,55),(66,9,54),(20,4,55),(42,12,53),(47,12,53),(23,10,54),(66,7,55),(48,11,52),(60,10,51),(68,9,52),(75,12,52),(72,12,54),(59,8,52),(57,8,54),(37,5,51),(76,3,51),(21,3,51),(50,10,53),(57,11,53),(49,1,52),(72,10,54),(62,3,55),(59,10,54),(67,9,54),(56,7,53),(60,5,52),(70,9,53),(36,9,53),(56,2,52),(51,9,51),(70,7,51),(59,9,55),(52,4,51),(52,8,51),(70,1,54),(74,6,53),(69,6,51),(33,3,54),(69,7,55),(35,5,52),(33,8,54),(69,5,53),(29,1,55),(67,1,53),(29,3,53),(65,4,53),(22,5,51),(75,8,53),(69,9,54),(32,9,54),(33,12,52),(64,11,51),(50,4,54),(73,8,53),(70,10,52),(35,7,54),(59,4,53),(28,8,53),(64,6,51),(74,10,52),(60,11,52),(30,6,51),(76,4,55),(23,9,51),(49,7,55),(33,11,54),(33,8,54),(44,7,52),(36,7,54),(31,10,55),(50,9,54),(58,8,51),(26,7,53),(35,11,51),(46,3,51),(67,9,52),(36,3,55),(65,3,54),(54,12,55),(57,12,53),(21,2,53),(20,7,51),(36,11,51),(44,5,52),(68,1,52),(40,4,55),(45,4,51),(63,10,55),(23,3,53),(57,7,55),(40,1,53),(31,1,55),(66,8,55),(41,12,53),(52,4,53),(46,1,53),(64,12,51),(34,12,54),(29,7,52),(64,1,52),(72,3,51),(35,11,52),(71,12,55),(43,4,55),(41,9,54),(30,4,55),(51,8,55),(59,6,53),(59,4,55),(23,6,54),(42,4,52),(51,2,53),(45,7,54),(34,7,54),(20,4,55),(27,6,52),(45,3,52),(43,11,51),(22,4,51),(50,7,51),(44,11,55),(25,7,54),(62,6,51),(39,5,51),(60,12,52),(76,5,53),(44,2,55),(26,1,51),(25,1,51),(53,4,51),(44,11,54),(67,10,53),(43,12,55),(40,10,54),(66,8,54),(58,9,53),(40,9,54),(67,2,53),(47,12,55),(46,8,51),(43,4,51),(37,1,51),(21,6,53),(55,1,55),(61,11,54),(45,9,55),(35,9,55),(69,6,52),(57,5,51),(48,4,51),(32,9,53),(29,11,54),(20,6,55),(56,9,52),(43,1,54),(32,11,54),(71,1,52),(63,7,52),(24,3,54),(52,11,54),(35,5,51),(67,12,54),(58,1,54),(71,11,53),(40,2,52),(48,7,51),(63,7,53),(65,2,55),(51,7,53),(44,6,52),(64,11,53),(60,7,51),(54,10,54),(56,11,51),(40,6,52),(55,5,51),(42,5,51),(29,6,53),(44,9,53),(73,9,55),(47,5,52),(45,9,51),(33,3,52),(43,10,51),(59,8,51),(48,7,53),(61,6,52),(48,8,54),(44,5,51),(66,9,52),(51,9,53),(52,3,54),(52,2,53),(26,12,54),(24,8,52),(44,11,55),(53,11,55),(47,12,53),(58,6,54),(67,10,54),(70,3,54),(44,8,55),(66,7,51),(60,2,53),(49,1,54),(25,6,52),(50,3,54),(73,6,51),(42,1,51),(69,4,53),(21,10,55),(22,4,51),(52,11,52),(46,8,54),(30,4,51),(48,8,53),(20,4,55),(53,11,53),(63,8,53),(47,5,55),(69,5,51),(36,12,55),(71,4,54),(51,3,55),(70,6,55),(60,6,52),(69,12,54),(64,7,54),(33,12,51),(35,1,51),(44,8,52),(29,11,52),(30,9,53),(57,6,55),(20,3,53),(60,5,55),(28,10,55),(41,9,53),(31,10,54),(71,8,54),(56,1,51),(37,12,52),(29,7,52),(55,10,54),(25,7,53),(50,6,53),(73,10,54),(50,7,51),(65,6,51),(24,6,53),(27,4,54),(58,12,54),(39,11,51),(23,4,54),(50,4,54),(51,3,55),(21,8,54),(57,5,53),(44,8,51),(29,3,54),(41,11,52),(31,12,55),(28,5,55),(49,9,55),(66,4,51),(55,8,53),(23,1,51),(42,2,51),(26,2,51),(57,3,52),(44,2,54),(57,6,54),(62,10,53),(75,4,51),(30,11,51),(70,11,55),(54,12,51),(53,1,55),(54,6,52),(60,4,52),(56,12,53),(44,2,53),(66,2,53),(28,4,53),(71,1,52),(64,8,51),(50,9,54),(24,1,52),(37,7,55),(56,12,54),(70,10,52),(29,10,55),(68,12,54),(26,4,51),(49,8,53),(73,5,53),(70,1,55),(23,11,55),(22,3,52),(43,4,54),(56,7,53),(57,10,51),(31,10,51),(44,5,55),(67,2,51),(43,4,54),(39,4,53),(31,2,53),(46,4,54),(44,3,52),(37,5,51),(31,8,55),(67,5,54),(57,6,55),(65,3,54),(30,5,54),(28,8,51),(26,11,53),(64,8,54),(28,4,54),(29,9,55),(67,3,52),(45,8,54),(34,12,51),(46,1,55),(32,7,52),(76,3,53),(73,8,55),(44,6,52),(22,9,53),(55,12,51),(48,7,52),(30,4,54),(36,5,55),(25,8,55),(63,6,51),(62,7,53),(51,11,53),(73,4,51),(56,1,54),(63,11,54),(76,2,52),(39,8,55),(55,1,53),(35,6,51),(24,3,52),(30,4,52),(21,6,54),(36,6,52),(74,2,52),(32,1,53),(74,11,51),(40,10,51),(63,2,55),(28,8,53),(22,12,54),(68,12,53),(52,2,55),(37,7,55),(20,2,54),(65,9,55),(26,5,52),(37,8,52),(65,11,55),(29,12,54),(61,3,54),(52,7,52),(73,8,52),(28,6,52),(44,2,55),(70,12,51),(67,1,55),(46,2,54),(72,7,55),(31,7,54),(30,10,53),(50,5,52),(42,7,51),(28,10,54),(45,11,52),(27,6,55),(47,6,51),(65,3,55),(31,7,51),(48,3,51),(22,1,55),(50,3,54),(49,1,52),(31,9,52),(27,1,51),(28,11,53),(43,3,51),(32,9,52),(27,3,51),(33,10,55),(59,2,54),(66,1,52),(73,4,52),(44,1,55),(65,7,52),(65,2,51),(35,7,53),(53,3,54),(43,5,55),(38,2,55),(43,4,54),(72,11,54),(56,7,51),(57,4,51),(71,2,52),(60,11,54),(70,9,52),(36,4,52),(48,6,51),(58,2,53),(55,3,54),(36,8,53),(43,10,55),(24,1,52),(29,1,54),(70,3,51),(28,8,54),(26,12,54),(54,12,55),(32,6,54),(44,6,53),(26,10,52),(53,3,53),(21,1,55),(35,5,55),(52,5,54),(67,1,51),(56,3,54),(34,10,51),(56,6,54),(31,6,55),(37,5,52),(66,2,54),(50,6,55),(64,2,53),(58,11,52),(28,1,54),(39,8,51),(48,1,54),(42,4,55),(43,4,51),(29,8,54),(52,2,54),(61,2,51),(65,3,54),(56,2,51),(38,12,55),(54,3,51),(63,7,55),(21,3,53),(71,2,52),(46,6,55),(32,6,55),(41,4,51),(26,11,55),(64,2,51),(42,10,53),(36,6,53),(26,9,53),(54,11,52),(75,8,55),(36,9,54),(27,8,53),(35,6,53),(37,5,55),(60,11,55),(57,8,55),(28,5,51),(54,4,53),(34,3,52),(54,12,51),(33,6,51),(57,7,52),(31,10,53),(23,8,51),(67,7,55),(48,2,53),(20,1,51),(26,9,53),(22,10,52),(41,7,55),(76,9,51),(20,4,53),(67,1,54),(47,9,55),(29,4,54),(54,1,51),(73,2,55),(35,4,52),(57,12,55),(25,11,53),(49,8,53),(47,12,55),(25,1,51),(34,5,52),(27,6,51),(43,10,54),(41,1,53),(31,1,51),(70,3,55),(33,9,51),(75,9,52),(66,4,52),(72,7,55),(54,1,53),(51,3,55),(45,1,52),(54,8,51),(27,6,52),(37,11,52),(36,8,55),(66,7,52),(47,1,52),(50,6,51),(56,3,55),(53,9,51),(75,11,55),(25,10,52),(71,11,52),(59,9,51),(52,3,52),(74,5,51),(30,1,52),(22,7,51),(42,3,55),(24,11,52),(40,7,53),(53,4,54),(26,8,54),(23,3,51),(74,7,55),(52,11,54),(22,6,54),(43,12,52),(38,6,52),(38,10,52),(40,1,51),(47,6,51),(53,12,53),(62,1,51),(69,12,55),(55,5,55),(53,12,55),(66,2,55),(30,12,51),(49,10,55),(37,4,51),(68,10,55),(62,10,53),(58,9,52),(52,8,54),(31,9,51),(58,10,53),(75,5,55),(32,4,53),(66,2,52),(43,1,53),(20,9,52),(50,8,51),(56,1,53),(47,4,54),(47,3,52),(22,3,53),(76,5,54),(37,6,54),(56,1,52),(69,2,52),(37,6,54),(22,2,54),(41,5,55),(56,10,54),(56,4,51),(59,9,55),(62,8,51),(51,10,51),(33,9,54),(56,5,53),(44,8,53),(71,2,54),(41,2,53),(62,1,54),(31,12,52),(65,8,54),(47,4,52),(37,10,51),(50,2,54),(23,8,52),(30,12,54),(53,10,53),(52,5,52),(58,4,54),(67,12,52),(59,4,53),(39,1,54),(72,3,53),(49,3,54),(21,6,55),(45,9,54),(25,5,52),(61,8,54),(25,5,54),(22,12,53),(48,5,54),(42,5,54),(46,1,53),(40,2,53),(58,8,55),(69,9,53);



CREATE TABLE `provincias` (
  `COD_REGION` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `COD_PROV` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMBRE_PROV` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `provincias` VALUES (15,10,'ARICA'),(15,11,'PARINACOTA'),(7,12,'TALCA'),(7,13,'CAUQUENES'),(8,14,'ARAUCO'),(8,15,'BIOBIO'),(8,16,'CONCEPCION'),(9,17,'CAUTIN'),(9,18,'MALLECO');



CREATE TABLE `regiones` (
  `COD_REGION` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOMBRE_REGION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `regiones` VALUES (7,'MAULE'),(8,'BIOBIO'),(9,'ARAUCANIA'),(15,'ARICA_PARANICOTA');



CREATE TABLE `tipo_arreglo` (
  `COD_ARREGLO` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `NOM_ARREGLO` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTO_ARREGLO` smallint DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO `tipo_arreglo` VALUES (51,'PONER_OJOS_DE_GATO',10),(52,'PAVIMENTAR',500),(53,'ASFALTAR',300),(54,'RIPIAR',100),(55,'ARREGLO CALLES',30);
```

Quiero generar una consulta que muestre el nombre de la región y el **monto total** que se gastó en trabajos en esa región, en un mes específico, pero el problema es que no hay ninguna columna que entregue tal cantidad si un trabajo se hace más de una vez dentro de un mes, y si intento usar un `count()` dentro de un `sum()`, devuelve un error. Hasta ahora tengo una consulta parcial que devuelve (claramente) los montos equivocados, ya que no encuentro una manera de contar los trabajos realizados.

```sql
SELECT regiones.NOMBRE_REGION, (historico.TIPO_ARREGLO * tipo_arreglo.MONTO_ARREGLO) AS TOTAL FROM historico
JOIN tipo_arreglo ON historico.TIPO_ARREGLO = tipo_arreglo.COD_ARREGLO
JOIN comunas ON historico.COD_COMUNA = comunas.COD_COMUNA
JOIN provincias ON comunas.COD_PROV = provincias.COD_PROV
JOIN regiones ON provincias.COD_REGION = regiones.COD_REGION
WHERE historico.MES = 1
GROUP BY regiones.NOMBRE_REGION;
```

Devuelve con `MES = 1`:

```
+------------------+-------+
| NOMBRE_REGION    | TOTAL |
+------------------+-------+
| BIOBIO           | 15900 |
| MAULE            | 1650  |
| ARAUCANIA        | 5400  |
| ARICA_PARINACOTA | 510   |
+------------------+-------+
```

Valores deseados con `MES = 1`:

```
+------------------+-------+
| NOMBRE_REGION    | TOTAL |
+------------------+-------+
| BIOBIO           | 18940 |
| MAULE            | 2730  |
| ARAUCANIA        | 9850  |
| ARICA_PARINACOTA | 1120  |
+------------------+-------+
```

Asumo que tengo que usar SELECT anidados, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con ellos, por lo que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida y agradecida.

**EDIT:** Se me había olvidado mencionar la lógica que quiero usar para el calculo, de ser posible:
**1.** Filtrar según el mes ingresado.
**2.** Contar las veces que los trabajos se repiten en un mes, ej.:

```
51 = 0 veces
52 = 1 vez
53 = 3 veces
54 = 2 veces
55 = 0 veces
```

**3.** Multiplicar las veces que los trabajos se hicieron por su monto.

```
0 * 10  = 0
1 * 500 = 500
3 * 300 = 900
2 * 100 = 200
0 * 30  = 0
```

**4.** Sumar los resultados de las multiplicaciones.

```
0 + 500 + 900 + 200 + 0 = 1600
```

**5.** Mostrar los resultados.

```
+------------------+-------+
| NOMBRE_REGION    | TOTAL |
+------------------+-------+
| PLACEHOLDER      | 1600  |
+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Entiendo con la pregunta, que quieres obtener en el resultado, la región, el tipo de trabajo, el número de veces que se ha realizado el trabajo, y el coste total de estos trabajo, todo ello para un mes determinado, es así?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendiendo lo que te dejo en el comentario, dejo una posible solución:

```
SELECT 
    regiones.NOMBRE_REGION,
    tipo_arreglo.NOM_ARREGLO,
    COUNT(*) AS numeroarreglos,
    SUM(tipo_arreglo.MONTO_ARREGLO) AS montototal
FROM 
    historico JOIN tipo_arreglo ON historico.TIPO_ARREGLO = tipo_arreglo.COD_ARREGLO
    JOIN comunas ON historico.COD_COMUNA = comunas.COD_COMUNA
    JOIN provincias ON comunas.COD_PROV = provincias.COD_PROV
    JOIN regiones ON provincias.COD_REGION = regiones.COD_REGION
WHERE 
    historico.MES = 1
GROUP BY 
    regiones.NOMBRE_REGION, tipo_arreglo.NOM_ARREGLO
```

También podríamos añadir y agrupar por el mes para no tener solo para un mes específico.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Es exactamente lo que necesitaba.